# A difficult integral (expectation of the function of a random variable)

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, beta-function

For $H>L$ , $p,q,\alpha,\beta>0$, and B(.,.) the beta functon, trying to solve this integral:

$$\mathbb{E}(X)_0^H=\frac{\alpha  H }{\beta  B(p,q)}\int_0^H \frac{x \left(\frac{-H \log \left(\frac{H-x}{H}\right)}{\beta }\right)^{\alpha  p-1} \left(\left(\frac{-H \log \left(\frac{H-x}{H}\right)}{\beta }\right)^{\alpha }+1\right)^{-p-q}}{H-x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

${\bf Motivation: }$ This is the partial expectation of the random variable $X \in[0,H]$, a  transformation of a r.v. following the generalized Beta distribution of second kind (also known as the Beta prime distribution).

${\bf Note: }$ I simplified the question and changed the support from $X \in [L,H]$ to $X \in [0,H]$.

Comment: Notation for partial expectation is still E(X)? P.S. I loved The Black Swan :D

Comment: Made notation clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can get into a somewhat more tractable form by basic transformations.
Taking $x=H-y$, $y=He^u$, $u = -\frac{\beta}{H} v$, we get \begin{equation} \frac{\alpha H}{B(p,q)} \int_0^{\infty} (1 - e^{-\frac{\beta}{H} v}) v^{\alpha p - 1} (v^\alpha + 1)^{-p-q} dv. \end{equation}
Taking a further transformation $v = z^{1/\alpha}$ gives 
\begin{equation}
\frac{H}{B(p,q)} \int_0^\infty (1-\exp(-\frac{\beta}{H}z^{1/\alpha})) z^{p-1} (z+1)^{-p-q} dz.
\end{equation}
I think the first form is better, and you could then try expanding the binomial and finding something in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik that will resum in a reasonable way.  Alternatively, find a way to express some set of terms on the inside as a simple integral and see if you can exchange the order of integration?

Comment: Okay, expanding the exponential in the second form gives $ \frac{H}{B(p,q)} \int \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!} (\frac{\beta}{H})^n z^{n/\alpha} z^{p-1} (z+1)^{-p-q} dz =? \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{H}{B(p,q)} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!} (\frac{\beta}{H})^n B(p+n/\alpha, q-n\alpha) $